# How to fix window to parent window?

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

How can I fix popup window (window.open()) to parent window? When I click to another tab my window is lost.

```
function popitup(url, w, h) {

    var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : window.screenX;
    var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : window.screenY;

    var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
    var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

    var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
    var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;

    popupWindow = window.open(url, title,"resizeable=yes,location=no,width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ",top=" + top + ",left=" + left + ", overflow-x=hidden");

    popupWindow.pw = pw;

    if (window.focus) {
        popupWindow.focus()
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Let go of the massively outdated notion that you had any control over actual window sizes on the client. My browser for example is configured to only ever open new full-size _tabs_ (instead of any actual “popups”), no matter what your code might try to do in that regard.

Comment: when we click outside window, that window is minimized, it loses focus, which should be the general behavior. Otherwise its working fine for me.
what value are you using for your title variable?

Comment: I missed the title in popitup function parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you want the popup attached to the page like that, don't use a popup at all; use an absolutely-positioned element within the page (for instance, a `div`) and load the relevant HTML into that `div`.